# Basil leaves varying in color, shape and reflectance

Tags: basil

I have bought basil plants from two different places and so far I have noticed that one of them has developed rounder, shinier and darker leaves than the other. why would that be, I thought there was only one species of basil (Ocimum basilicum). The less shiny paler one was bought as a seedling while the darker rounder one was grown from seed. They both have the recognizeable basil smell so I do still think that they are both basil.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous cultivars of basil. You seem to have two of them here.

Answer (score 0):

Top photo seems like Thai Basil (purplish flower).
Bottom photo seems like sweet Italian Basil (white flower).